# Error 10054 when connecting google service

Tags: python, google-api, python-requests, urllib3

I tried to connect to google api and got this error

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=ru-RU (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)
```

this is my code, i used library urllib3,urllib2,requests but it did not help

```
import requests

recording = 'C:/Users/sborovskiy/PycharmProjects/VoiceManager/com/work/voiceManager/output.flac'
url = 'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=ru-RU'
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'audio/x-flac; rate=16000', 'User-Agent': 'Netscape 6.0'}
files = {'output.flac' : open(recording, 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url = url, data = files, headers = headers)
```

internet not give a specific answer

Comment: Sounds like Google is rejecting your connection to their undocumented private API. Perhaps your IP has been banned?

Comment: Ie take you this code works without error?I'll try to check, but I do not think what my account is banned

Comment: need use v2 api.v1 closed